# C++ coroutine segfaults when passing value through promise type

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, coroutine

I have a coroutine that `co_awaits` three times to pick up new iterators feed in by the caller using the `feed()` function of the return type `Parser`. The values are stored within promise type and delivered on `Awaitable::resume()` to referenced iterators from within the coroutine body (sorry I'm new to couroutines and I bet there's a better way to do that, please feel free to show me). In any case, this code segfaults:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxAGBAA6oCoRODB7evgGkyamOAqHhUSyx8f6BdpgO6UIETMQEmT5%2BlZj2BQx1DQRFkTFxCbb1jc3ZlSO9Yf2lgxUAlLaoXsTI7Bzm/mHI3lgA1Cb%2BbsgKBPioh9gmGgCCm9u7mAdHaMTLjuGX13dmWww7Xn2hzcp2IYWAAH0AG54TAAdy%2Bt2%2BoK8Dj2yjeLDwSkOViRtxRaOUDSUxD2ID2iS80VoeGQe1O6BAKBI72mEIQhnQ9GBGNQWJx/mwBwA7Hi7rc9lK9l5UkZKZjsZgIQQAJ6JJ6HAAi5JAfIFmFx32%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%2BbiFk1CtsGEAqExCE/KVCAewIBBsTjMq0JS8rVPw9KwjSMRtN01xcoYVBMFUNZEgbDa32vL6MIhcIXTJVDJNmmSO3u3DnqmmhmFoT6FD0u1M1%2B/7AeB2iR3B9AITEZtVQUHb4b2xGKyUqtJpDDLuNrQwFH4YgWAM5lRqakErw/Vrx03fqHzIUGhd6icxcGprhRGxrqNo09W3bWHdv2sVFbG7yaDTAhXx14hvKUJ0SqRlKmctTXoSKnGmJYsL2LMMxNeje24uE0TXfEh7GeegB6QOXrh6S9uhMQFNy2GQtYl23Zp2TCuKr2Et93FkdNKavAYTz6FJ/HMCB9IY9qgPHomm4ptV89xBASK5swbL1tolPMIcvC4%2BdiLMuinxMDTn2zD9urFzc/sDQ2429bG04kvQ0mJ/OpRp4GvnTeqAQSqeq2JWr5nDviY6bTtb0nWht16BVC5msFm8RdotLI3nDd7Nq630pYVURYnnqvwDLDDcWEnpOUVEoDM3ljYT1ht/EW3lYjADCBmV8cCNzeW%2Bu/emR4K4JimkZVuQYj4dgTMOe%2Bn42oy1/P%2BMkkFDaL2rHhYOVpT5cGwmgMmmlJZ8y9OQ4W35qFdUlg/ARA0aFfBgnQ5CGEQHZlLEwkO1pbRmHYagThZ5uGNV4e%2BERfVBEkG6nw6Wot9Hy1hlIxesjsLYWYUo9A/hVHqMIJosa2jrwUJFh1GhhidEeNEeLCRaELGuCsaQ6UHDNalRUt8UKewWAtgYGXKuZDfH8IDJSHoXAYGuwABLtFoOlVIxA4quwXv/ShcIMmNDMNkswOTUCVOxHJBATw4QkFoJhdARUjCHAAGIcTKUYgB8IqkEH8LUiwBgABe4JaCqmmgxTCRSSkqN3nhYh38GppjiBPAho8wlSk2SSOIetT4QC2QQLg%2BznpHO2SbOx5yegjwXrc0kpzbSPMaP4a5e8OCLFoJwQSvA/AcC0KQVAnA3DWGsAyZYqxNS/B4KQAgmg/mLAANYgEkGGbygkACcIoAAcXAzCEpFASjQhL/CEsEvoTgkhgWovBZwXgCgQAaGRaixYcBYAwEQCyFgiQ6BxHIJQNAgrhXxGAAoZgiQFAIFQIbLAMI1gADUAwAHk9KcCRTQWgA02UQGiEy6IYQGiqh1bwU1zBiCqg1ctValrSDirYIIDVDA5lMqwPEow4hQW8HwKRGoLo2X%2BqCKoaoFp1hgtCu0JltJoh/ltR4LATK1wsEtYsKgBhpXqvhFqxgTr%2BCCBEGIdgUgZCCEUCodQYbdBcH0IYYw0LLD6DwNENlkBFioBLgIUNVEqKMm1KYSw1gzAaDygAdTELQPKGqFCsvaKtdILgMJjD8A2kI0wShlD0HkNIAh117pSAehgfQd2DAbVUGoAhuijE8C0PQ17Oh3qmMUAY8Qr2TCPV%2Bno56P0SEWAoOFaxAN0o4EC0gIKwUQo4HsVQhKwxUTDJIaayB6QQHkgwdFmYIC4EICQA4iL5i8BRf6%2BYGKQCCQ5QCjgDLSAZupd5PFkg8VhhFFwEUIozCSFJYSxDUGmWwdZeyzl5HSA8v5e8KkhsKAQHFUK%2BgxAIisHWAhpDKG0P0hJd5MwvBbQEbBEyBtxbhCiHEBW0z1a1BMvraQOEf5EiZvA5B6DvBYMaotDJvYqAqDwcQ8h1DwB0N7Ew3WbDuGPASqU0R/wVzSNcsWC08igwUG0foxmsMXBvIaGo/4UlrsRSCQ41wCtbnmUcBExysjWgKOkExYJfw3lJAaDMFwMlJLWt4q4Fl2ltH/CMrDcJsTtX/mcD04JobLKRtotINDVIzhJBAA%3D)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <coroutine>
#include <string_view>

struct Promise;

struct Parser : public std::coroutine_handle<Promise> {

    using promise_type = ::Promise;

    auto feed(std::convertible_to<std::string_view> auto&& view);

    ~Parser() {
        destroy();
    }
};

struct Awaitable {
    Promise* promise;
    std::string_view::iterator& start_;
    std::string_view::iterator& end_;

    Awaitable(std::string_view::iterator& start, std::string_view::iterator& end)
        : start_{ start }
        , end_{ end }
    { }
    auto await_ready() -> bool { printf("await_ready!\n"); return true; }
    auto await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<Promise> handle) {
        promise = &handle.promise();
        printf("await_resume!\n");
    }
    auto await_resume() -> void;
};

struct Promise {
    std::pair<std::string_view::iterator, std::string_view::iterator> iterpair;

    auto get_return_object() -> Parser { return {Parser::from_promise(*this)}; };
    auto initial_suspend() noexcept -> std::suspend_never { return {}; }
    auto final_suspend() noexcept -> std::suspend_always { return {}; }
    auto await_transform(std::pair<std::string_view::iterator, std::string_view::iterator> iterpair) -> Awaitable { return {iterpair.first, iterpair.second}; }
    auto return_void() { printf("return void!\n"); }
    // auto return_value() { printf("return void!\n"); }
    auto unhandled_exception() {}
};

auto Awaitable::await_resume() -> void {
    printf("await_resume!\n");
    start_ = promise->iterpair.first;
    end_ = promise->iterpair.second;
}

auto Parser::feed(std::convertible_to<std::string_view> auto&& view) {
    auto my_view = std::string_view{ view };
    promise().iterpair = { my_view.begin(), my_view.end() };
}


auto coro() -> Parser {

    std::string_view::iterator start, end;

    // feed1
    co_await std::pair<std::string_view::iterator, std::string_view::iterator>{ start, end };
    
    // feed2
    co_await std::pair<std::string_view::iterator, std::string_view::iterator>{ start, end };
    
    // feed3
    co_await std::pair<std::string_view::iterator, std::string_view::iterator>{ start, end };

    co_return;
}

int main() {

    std::string_view part1 = "Hello sir!";
    std::string_view part2 = "How is the world doing?";
    std::string_view part3 = "Blazingly good sir!";

    Parser myparser = coro();

    myparser.feed(part1);
    myparser.feed(part2);
    myparser.feed(part3);
}
```

And I can't point my finger why it does so. Any hints?

Comment: `await_ready()` always returns `true`, therefore `await_suspend()` isn't called and so `promise` is never set.

Answer (score 2):

`await_ready()` returning `true` means the coroutine will not be suspended, and thus `await_suspend` will not be invoked.

Since `await_suspend` is not called, `promise` is not initialized. Then, when `await_resume()` is executed, `start_ = promise->iterpair.first;` uses the dangling pointer `promise`, which causes the crash.

Comment: Uff thx! How very unintuitive. From my perspective it made sense that the coroutine is ready to await, but hey...

Comment: @glades it's more like "is the awaitable ready to return a result?" If not, then suspend and resume when a result is ready to be returned.

Comment: @guard3 Ok but what value will the awaitable return if it's ready? I find nothing specific in the docs ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines)

Comment: @glades the return value of an awaitable, or more specifically of a `co_await` expression is whatever `await_resume` returns.